# Passing self as argument to a Protocol function that wants same type as self as the argument

Tags: swift, generics, delegates, swift2, swift-protocols

I'm writing an async dictionary that returns a Future with the value:

- immediately if it's already cached, or
- after the (network) operation if it isn't yet

The dictionary inside my class is generic, so the class is as well. Currently the user has to read the docs and know to set the `dataCall` function, which is how the dictionary knows how to get a value for a key, in the form

```
var dataCall: ((key: Key) -> Future<Value, MyError>)?
```

But this requires other programmers to know about the data call and set it.
So I wrote a protocol

```
protocol CacheDelegate {
    typealias T: Hashable
    typealias U
    func dataCallForCacheManager(cacheManager: CacheManager<T, U>) → (key: T) → Future<Value, MyError>
}
```

However, then if I try and call this in `init()` as

`delegate.dataCallForCacheManager(self)`

I get the error

> Cannot invoke `dataCallForDictionary` with an argument list of type '(CacheManager)'

I also cannot make a `var delegate: CacheDelegate?` because

> Protocol `CacheDelegate` can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

So I find myself in a pickle where I can't pass myself as an argument, and I can't set a delegate to get my data call from this protocol. Am I missing something? I'm willing to do Swift 2 Voodoo.

The contents of a toy example (without Futures and the dictionary and everything) is below:

```
import Foundation

protocol Delegate {
    typealias T: Hashable
    typealias U
    func dataCallForDictionary(dictionary: MyDictionary<T, U>) -> (T) -> (U)
}

struct MyDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    typealias T = Key
    typealias U = Value

    init<Object: Delegate>(delegate: Object) {
        dataCall = delegate.dataCallForDictionary(self)
//        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    var delegate: Delegate?

    var dataCall: ((key: Key) -> Value)?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your example, have you considered doing:

```
protocol Delegate {
    func dataCallForDictionary<T: Hashable, U>(dictionary: MyDictionary<T, U>) -> T -> U
}

struct MyDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    var delegate: Delegate?
    var dataCall: ((key: Key) -> Value)?

    init(delegate: Delegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        dataCall = delegate.dataCallForDictionary(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so you made the Delegate not be a generic, and instead put the generic constraints on the method. It's a work-around, but it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, my own implementation doesn't work for me, the call gets autocompleted as generic, and it doesn't accept my parameters. I guess I'll just pass the dataCall as an initializer so that the struct is self-documenting. Thanks for the workaround, but I missed the point completely :(

Answer (score 0):

I think delegate in `MyDictionary` struct should be weak.